# Reference for cd_deployer_conf.xml & cd_storage_conf.xml config files

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, configuration

Where can I find a complete reference for cd_deployer_conf.xml  & cd_storage_conf.xml config files ?  I see the notes in the files & snippets of info on sdllivecontent.com, but I was hoping for one source that explained all the settings.

Comment: I don`t know which sdllivecontent snippets are you talking about but in **"Implementing Content Delivery > Reference section > Configuration file references"** there is a complete list of all the configuration tags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've never seen this  kind of a unifying document before.  Typically on SDL Live Content the relevant configuration elements are listed in the instructions for the component you're configuring.

Perhaps you can open up a documentation enhancement request via the Ideas site or add a comment on the most relevant page on SDL Live Content.

Comment: +1. The .xsd schema files also let us validate config files to an extent, but SDL Live Content is the way to get detailed information. For deployer and storage, I typically follow [Nuno's post on manually setting these up](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html).

Answer (score 10):

Another useful resource are the examples supplied in the Tridion Install Package.

{TRIDION_INSTALLER_ZIP}\Content Delivery\resources\configurations

Here you will find well commented versions of configuration files.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any single resource for these.  As Chris mentions, the comments in the sample config files are very useful.

There are some great posts about specific sections of each of these config files on the old Tridion Forums (login required).  In particular the following forums:

- [Content Delivery](https://forum.tridion.com/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=132)
- [Publishing](https://forum.tridion.com/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=114)
- [Installation](https://forum.tridion.com/forum.asp?FORUM_ID=118)

There are also some nuggets on the Tridion World site.  For example, [the "IIS Deployer for .NET (Manual Configuration)" article](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/howto_iis_deployer.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Not what you're searching for, but I find myself more & more just looking at the samples I created [here](http://code.google.com/p/kickstart-tridion-environment/source/browse/#svn/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/CreateAnEnvironmentForMe/ConfigSamples). These files just cover the basics, and obviously don't document what they do. I find that with years of practice these files just make sense... unfortunately it takes years of practice.

I agree with the suggestion to ask for additional detail on the documentation - or perhaps someone "from the community" could write something about it, I can review it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides all that, you also have the XSD of those configs both on the installation media ([Installation_Media]\Content Delivery\resources\schemas) and on [Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/reference_EF801D43AE014C19BE3E9098206D97A4).